# Let $H, H_n \in L_p^*$ such that $H_n (f) := H(f1_{X_n})$ for all $f \in L_p$. Are there some relations between $H, H_n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Fix $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $L_p := L_p (X, \mu, E)$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L_p}$ be its norm. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Let $(X_n)$ a countable measurable partition of $X$ such that $\mu(X_n) < \infty$. Let $L_p^* := L_p (X, \mu, E)^*$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L^*_p}$ be its norm. Let $H \in L_p^*$. We define $H_n \in L_p^*$ by
$$
H_n (f) := H(f1_{X_n}) \quad \forall f \in L_p.
$$

By [dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) $\| f1_{\cup_{i=1}^n X_i} - f\|_{L_p} \to 0$ and thus $\sum_{i=1}^n H_i \to H$ weakly as $n \to \infty$. I feel it's not possible to have convergence in norm, i.e.,
$$
\bigg \|\sum_{i=1}^n H_i -H \bigg \|_{L^*_p}  \not\to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.
$$

Could you confirm if my understanding is correct? Is there some relation between the norms of $H, H_n$?

Comment: I think if $H\in L^{p'}(X,E^*)$ then you will have the convergence for $p>1$ by dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: If $p=1$ you cannot have convergence in norm in general, already for $E=\mathbb R$.

Comment: @daw Assume $p \in (1, \infty)$ and $X^{*}$ has the [Radon-Nikodým property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546633/construct-conditional-expectation-on-banach-spaces-with-radon-nikod%c3%bdm-property) with respect to $\mu$. Then there is an isometric isomorphism $\varphi:L_{p}(\mu, X)^* \to L_{q} (\mu, X^*)$ where $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$. Let
$$
K_n := \sum_{i=1}^n H_i \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.
$$
[...]

Comment: [...] Then $\|K_n\|_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*} \le \|H\|_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*}$ and $K_n \to H$ pointwise. It follows that $\|\varphi(K_n)\|_{L_{q}(\mu, X^*)} \le \|\varphi(H)\|_{L_{q}(\mu, X^*)}$. However, I could **not** get how $\varphi(K_n) \to \varphi(H)$ pointwise. Could you elaborate more?