# Does an isometric automorphism of $L_p (\mu, X)$ preserve pointwise convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Let $p, q \in (1, \infty)$ such that $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$. In an attempt to formalize the ideas in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577980/let-h-h-n-in-l-p-such-that-h-n-f-hf1-x-n-for-all-f-in-l-p-a#comment9636279_4577980), I have come across below questions, i.e.,

1. Let $\psi$ is an isometric automorphism of $L_{p}(\mu, X)$. Let $f, f_n \in L_{p}(\mu, X)$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise $\mu$-a.e. Does $\psi(f_n) \to \psi(f)$ pointwise $\mu$-a.e.?
2. Let $X^{*}$ have the [Radon-Nikodým property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546633/construct-conditional-expectation-on-banach-spaces-with-radon-nikod%c3%bdm-property) with respect to $\mu$. Then there is an isometric isomorphism $\varphi:L_{p}(\mu, X)^* \to L_{q} (\mu, X^*)$. Let $H,H_n \in L_{p}(\mu, X)^*$ such that $H_n \to H$ pointwise. Does $\varphi(H_n) \to \varphi(H)$ pointwise $\mu$-a.e.?

I feel that isometric isomorphisms do not preserve pointwise convergence. However, I could not come up with a counter-example. Could you elaborate on my questions?

Comment: What is the relevance of $(E,|\cdot|)$?

Comment: @uniquesolution I forgot to mention that here i used Bochner integral.

Comment: Do you know the answer to your question when $E=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: So your $L_p(\mu,X)$ is not really $L_p(\mu,X)$, but a space of functions from $X$ taking values in $E$, correct?

Comment: @uniquesolution No. I only know a non-trivial isometric isomorphism in case $\Omega = E=\mathbb R$ as follows, i.e., $f\mapsto f(x+\cdot)$ for some fixed $x \in \mathbb R$. However, for this particular isometric isomorphism, the answers for above questions are positive.

Comment: @uniquesolution You are right! I meant $L_p(\mu, X) := L_p(X, \mu, E)$.

Comment: You may want to look for characterizations of isometries of $L_p$ spaces. For the classical spaces, it already appears in Banach's book. May also suggest that you try to write what you actually mean.

Comment: Reason for a downvote...?

Comment: 1. Misleading and inaccurate notation, and ignoring the need to fix it.
2. Formulation is too general -- should begin with the "easiest" problem you can't solve, e.g. $E=R$ 3. "Feeling like something" in mathematics is not really an effort to solve a problem.

Comment: Those are terribly bad reasons for downvoting, really

Answer (score 1):

If the convergence of $f_n$ is also in $L_p$ then you can extract a subsequence converging pointwise for the isometric sequence.
Wlog, we can assume $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise $\mu-a.e.$.
Assume $|f_n(x)| \leq |g(x)|$ with $g \in L_p$, then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L_p$. Hence $\psi(f_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ in $L_p$. Hence there is a subsequence $\psi(f_{n_i}) \rightarrow 0$ pointwise $\mu$-a.e.

Assume $|f_n(x)| \leq |g(x)|$ with $g \in L_p$:
as $\psi$ is an isometry:
$$\int |\psi(f_n)|^p = \int |f_n|^p$$
$$\int I_{E_n}|\psi(f_n)|^p \leq \int |f_n|^p$$
where $E_n = \{x: |\psi(f_n)| \geq \epsilon\}$.
$$\epsilon^p \mu(E_n) \leq \int |f_n|^p$$
taking limit on both sides:
$$\epsilon^p \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int |f_n|^p = \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  |f_n|^p = 0$$
Hence for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n) = 0$, we now need to prove $ \mu(\cup_{n \geq k} E_n) \rightarrow 0$. See if u can get this under some conditions. For example, $ \mu(\cup_{n \geq k} E_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ can be proved by assuming $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n \geq k} ||f_n||_p = 0$.
So atleast $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n \geq k} ||f_n||_p = 0$ implies pointwise convergence of $\psi(f_n)$ to $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not answer the essential part of my question. My concern is pointwise convergence not that in $L_p$... It would be great if you can provide counter-examples.

Comment: Also, I do not downvote your answer...

Comment: Hi Akira, no problem. I have added some more derivation. Check if its useful for you.

Comment: @Akira Added some more comments. check it out. cheers.